# How to change my Thread implementation to use ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I had been making a game, and was using Threads in my program to carry out tasks. So let me explain the scenario a bit. I have a BattleManager class which implements Runnable and keep looping in the battle queue for battles, if there are any.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while(serverRunning){
            synchronized (battleQueue) {
                for(Battle battle : battleQueue){
                    if(battle != null){
                        if (battle instanceof WildBattle) {
                            if(!((WildBattle) battle).isBattleOver()){
                                ((WildBattle) battle).tryExecuteBattleTurn();
                            }else{
                                battleQueue.remove(battle);
                                battle = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        currentThread = null;
    }
```

Then I check if battle is not over, and if not I try to execute the battle turn. Since there can be more than 100 battles running at the same time and there are complex calculations inside every battle, I inside WildBattle class spawn a child thread to execute the task, so that the battles run in parallel.

Here is the method which is invoked inside wild battle class, which spawns a new thread.

```
 public void tryExecuteBattleTurn() {
        if (!isBattleTurnRunning && battleThread == null) {

            battleThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    executeBattle();
                    battleLog.setBattleLog("");
                    battleThread = null;
                    //System.err.println("Total execution time : " +(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
                }
            }, "Battle thread");

            battleThread.start();
        }
    }
```

Now the main question is, I want to learn about executor service and I read at few places that it is always better to use executor service rather than spawning new child threads. How can I change this to use executor service.
I am not sure though. I am not a java expert and still learning the language so spare me if you see something is wrong, and please let me know if I can change anything to make it more efficient. 
Let me know if you are not clear about anything.

Comment: On a basic level the transition is very simple: throw out all the looping and delay code from your `Runnable`s and whenever you'd spawn a new thread you pass your `Runnable` to a `ScheduledExecutor` instead.

Comment: Can you please post an example of that :) as I am really not sure about what you mean. And what will be the advantage of using ScheduledExecutor.

Comment: @Shehks It's difficult to figure out from the code what your concurrency requirements are. For example, who sets the `isBattleTurnRunning` field? Do you currently create a new thread at every turn?

Comment: inside the executeBattle(). When the executeBattle() is finished executing the thread is changed to null and isTurnOver flag is set to false. My bad that I used executeBattle() as the method name, should be executeBattleTurn(); So yep I create a new Thread every battle turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you a basic example and you'll manage how to integrate it with your code

First you create `ExecutorService` somewhere in your application.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
```

You should choose `NUMBER_OF_THREADS` based on your application needs. Threads are not created immediately - only when you submit a task to service and there are no available threads for it. If all `NUMBER_OF_THREADS` are busy, task will wait in queue until one of the threads will be able to handle it. `ExecutorService` will reuse threads, this will save time on thread instantiation and is a generally good concept to work with threads.

Then you manage how to access executor service from your battles. Then, when you need to perform an asynchronous work you submit task to service:

```
executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

If your application has a lifecycle and can be somehow shutdown, you'd like to shutdown `ExecutorService` as well. There are two options - `shutdown()` and `shutdownNow()`, first one waits for all current tasks to be executed, second one performs shutdown immediately and returns list of tasks that were not completed.

As was mentioned in comments, you should figure out how to preserve model state and organize thread synchronization based on your real situation.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer, but in the answer your posted, you have NUMBER_OF_THREADS, How will I know the number on threads when making new instance of ExecutorService as the number of battle threads will not be fixed. Also when should I start the executor service and when should I shut it down as I read it somewhere you have to start it and shut it down.

Comment: There is no requirement, that number of threads == number of your battles. Though you created a thread per battle before, this is not a good solution, because server can fall if number is too big. You should create pool with as many threads as your server can handle.

Comment: When to start - there is no "start" event in executor service - it creates threads gradually when they are needed. There is, however, shutdown method. If your application has a lifecycle and it can be shutdown somehow, then you'd like to shutdown ExecutorService as well.

Comment: All right, I will get back to you after trying it out. I don't have anything to synchronize in these runnables so I suppose all I will need to do is, in tryExecuteBattleTurn(), I will access the executorService object and submit the new runnable rather than creating a new Thread. Everything else should remain the same.

Comment: I made it work with executorService. Not sure how it will affect the performance, but everything works perfectly for now :) I have used TotalSize to be equal to toal number of processors + 1, but I guess I will need to scale it up as I can have more than 100 battles running at the same time.